# Isset not working on submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

This is one view(templateUrl of a state), and the isset for some reason dosent work properly.. I at the bottom of the code by passing in if(isset($_POST["submit"])){do this} . But it doesent do that. And i clearly gave it a name attribute of "submit" and a type attribute of "submit". Please help Thankyou:

```
    <?php
var_dump($_GET);
require_once('PhpConsole.phar');
require_once('connection.php');
  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="page">

    <h1>Registration </h1>
    <form  method = "post">
          <input  type = "text" name = "username" placeholder = "Username"required/>
          <br>
          <input  type = "text"name = "email" placeholder = "Email"required/>
          <br>
          <input type = "text" placeholder = "password" name = "password" required/>
          <br>
          <input type = "submit" name = "submit"/>
    </form>
    </div>
<?php
$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

  $query = "INSERT INTO authe (authe.Email , authe.Password, authe.Username) VALUES ('".$email."', '".$password."' , '".$username."')";
  if($result = $connection->query($query))
  {
  header("Location: http://localhost:8012/phpForm/login.php");
  }
  else{
    echo "Something Went wrong...";
  }
}
 ?>

</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: what is with the spaces? `<form  method = "post">`

Comment: That didnt help. Updating code above @samayo

Comment: Yea but that wont help with the button sadly @RiggsFolly :( But thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You have 2 buttons? Are you sure you are pressing the right one???

Comment: What is an `<md-whiteframe>` its not a HTML tag I recognise

Comment: What isn't working, does it display "Not Submited.." at all? I've copied this code and it works fine. Are there any errors in your logs?

Comment: `<body>` isn't necessary as it would be added later on while rendering anyway.

Comment: same. I tested locally no issues.

Comment: let me test the printR. Yes i am pressing the right one @RiggsFolly

Comment: Dont rely on submit button, add a hidden input value and check that. include print_r($_POST); there, post here output.

Comment: <md-whiteframe> is a angular-material tag.

Comment: What do you mean the HTML Is a mess? @RiggsFolly. That is clean code

Comment: Well adding an Angularjs tag might well have given us a bit of a clue

Comment: @RiggsFolly not sure mate, I tested locally without any body tag, plain form tags and a submit button, works fine for me.

Comment: @RiggsFolly when i did the print_r($_POST);  I got as a anwser: array()

Comment: When i do var_dump it gives me array (size=0)  @RiggsFolly

Comment: well that's the issue, you don't have anything in your POST array. Try removing the md-whiteframe thing and see if you get anything at all..

Comment: the md-whiteframe is essential for the design but let me test it out @Vincent

Comment: Tried the above code @Vincent . Same thing..

Comment: Okay, I'm not entirely sure about this, but try adding an action attribute to your form tag `<form action=" " method="post" >` , although its not necessary at all, I think some browsers might make a fuss out of it.

Comment: Oh ok ima try that @Vincent

Comment: You tagged as angular and javascript but there's no code to support the question. Plus, how are you accessing this; local, hosted? If local, as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or as `c:///file.xxx`? 2 different animals here.

Comment: its locally.. localhost/file.something @Fred-ii- . This has to do with angular since im using a angular-component. And it has to do with javascript since im using angular.

Comment: you need to post your full code then. Maybe your controller's not firing up, hard to say. and why the `var_dump($_GET);` if there's no get?

Comment: Because i always do that? Thats obviously not the problem @Fred-ii-

Comment: Doesn't make sense that this would be used as an angular `templateUrl` ... there would be no post sent to it. Not enough known about how you use this. Also why would it have head, body etc for a state view?

Comment: @Dsafds I am confused by your last two edits.  You seem to have significantly altered the original code and removed any reference to Angular.  Are you still having difficulties with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tested, this plain PHP code works,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <h1>
                Registration 
            </h1>
            <form  method = "post">
                <input  type = "text" name = "username" placeholder = "Username"required/>
                <br>
                <input  type = "text"name = "email" placeholder = "Email"required/>
                <br>
                <input type = "text" placeholder = "password" name = "password" required/>
                <br>
                <input type = "submit" name = "submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
            print_r($_POST); 
            if(isset($_POST["username"])){
                $username = $_POST["username"];
            }
            if(isset($_POST["email"])){
                $email = $_POST["email"];
            }
            if(isset($_POST["password"])){
                $password = $_POST["password"];
            }
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
                    echo $username .PHP_EOL;
                    echo $email .PHP_EOL;
                    echo $password .PHP_EOL;
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now as requested by others please post non-working code with Angular components to help further.